# Display javascript/html code like plain text in react.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

How to display javascript/html code in react.js render.

I have tried like this

```
var thisIsMyCopy = '<p>copy copy copy <strong>strong copy</strong </p>';

return (
    <div>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: thisIsMyCopy}}>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

This is html code.. but i also want to display javascript code on my screen... how i can do that..
Can you guide me.. how to proceed with it

Comment: You should never ever have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. I recommend you stop right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its already in a stringed version, just need to include the variable inside curly braces. `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is for when you want to turn a html string into actual html.

```
var thisIsMyCopy = '<p>copy copy copy <strong>strong copy</strong </p>';

return (
  <div>
    {thisIsMyCopy}
  </div>
)
```

if you want a string version of a function just take whatever function and add a string to it like so:

```
function functionString() { console.log('stringed function") }

var functionAsString = '' + functionString

return (
  <div>
    {functionAsString}
  </div>
)
```

Here is a working pen demonstrating this http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/JRqEWW

Comment: Can you be more specific by what you mean? like stringified javascript functions? As you would see them in the code editor?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display the "code" in html, you can use

```
<code>something</code>
```

tag and it will display your code onto the screen.

Comment: But only in HTML5 ;)